# Filtering Table using BETWEEN but data are not showing up

Tags: java, mysql, string, swing, string-comparison

I am trying to filter my table by Month using combobox but whenever I  select October nothing shows up even the timestamp from my database is October.

Here is my code:

```
String monthSelection = cbbMonthSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (monthSelection == "Month") {
    System.out.println("month");
} else if (monthSelection == "October") {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentlogin", "root", "");
        //String sql = "SELECT * FROM studentregisterlogin WHERE TimeIn BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-31 00:00:00' AND SSN=" +jftfSearch.getText();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM studentregisterlogin WHERE TimeIn>='2020-10-01 01:00:00' AND TimeIn<='2020-10-31 23:59:59'";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeQuery();
        jtTableTime.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
} else if (monthSelection == "November") {
    System.out.println("november");
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but still the data are not showing up

Comment: Can you add the create table and insert statement of some rows? The first query you commented out has an additional filter (SSN). Remove it from your post if not needed. The problem is about swing or mysql query ?

Comment: Don't  use `==` for object comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I already fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding rs = to pst.executeQuery(); solve the problem